# OnCheckedChanged not called after a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am a new developer and I what I am trying to accomplish is hiding the radio buttons in the bottom DIV and the btnSetFinishState when clicked shows the bottom DIV (which it does from code behind). But the radio buttons when clicked do not fire the code behind method.

Here is .aspx:

```
<div class="row">
   <asp:Button ID="btnSetFinishState" runat="server" Text="FINISHED" OnClick="btnSetFinishState_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Enabled="False" />
</div>

<div class="row" id="finishedBlock" runat="server" visible="false">
   <asp:Label ID="lblSetFinishText" runat="server" Text="Are you sure you want to set state to finished?" />
   <div data-toggle="buttons" id="divRadioButtons">
      <label id="btnFinishyes" class="btn btn-default col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
         <asp:RadioButton ID="finishyes" Text="Yes" GroupName="finish" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="finishyes_CheckedChanged" />
      </label>
      <label id="btnFinishno" class="btn btn-default col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
         <asp:RadioButton ID="finishno" Text="No" GroupName="finish" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="finishno_CheckedChanged" />
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

The aspx.cs code:

```
protected void btnSetFinishState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if neither radio button clicked
    if (!finishyes.Checked && !finishno.Checked)
    {
        finishedBlock.Visible = true; // show the radio button DIV
        //return;
    }
}

protected void finishno_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    finishedBlock.Visible = false; // hide the radio buttons
    finishno.Checked = false; // reset the no button to false
}

protected void finishyes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // set the finished state code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my machine and found event's are firing exactly.
So , I think the different between your environment and mine may be **<%@ Page** directive and missing **AutoEventWireup="true"** property.

Please share  your Asp.net version and project info such as 
is there any master pages or not.

**UPDATE:**
Please create a new sample web form application in visual studio and add a new web form say 'form1', paste your aspx and code behind to the newly added 'form1'. Test and if successfull then check the difference in aspx and code behind with your existing project.Also please let us know.

Comment: I copied and pasted his code and it does not work and I have autoeventwireup true...  this is weird.

Comment: I have it in my page directive. <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NPSQuestionnaire.aspx.cs" Inherits="NPSMobile.assets.WebForm1" %>

Comment: No master pages. VS2012 .NET ver 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Is there e reason why btnSetFinishState is set to Enabled="False" ?

Because I tested this code and it works

aspx code

```
 <div class="row">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSetFinishState" runat="server" Text="FINISHED" OnClick="btnSetFinishState_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Enabled="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="finishedBlock" runat="server" visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSetFinishText" runat="server" Text="Are you sure you want to set state to finished?" />
        <div data-toggle="buttons" id="divRadioButtons">
            <label id="btnFinishyes" class="btn btn-default col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="finishyes" Text="Yes" GroupName="finish" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="finishyes_CheckedChanged" />
            </label>
            <label id="btnFinishno" class="btn btn-default col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="finishno" Text="No" GroupName="finish" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="finishno_CheckedChanged" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSetFinishState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if neither radio button clicked
        if (!finishyes.Checked && !finishno.Checked)
        {
            finishedBlock.Visible = true; // show the radio button DIV
            //return;
        }
    }

    protected void finishno_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finishedBlock.Visible = false; // hide the radio buttons
        finishno.Checked = false; // reset the no button to false
    }

    protected void finishyes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set the finished state code
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, ignore the Enabled="False", forgot to get rid of that first. It is enabled from code behind.

Comment: Um... nope. I have done so many other fixes and adds around it but this one just sits. Odd. I know as stand alone, it should work. I have no idea what is causing this. When I click a radio button, nothing happens.